# Websocket can't connect to ActionController::Live - failed with 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  include ActionController::Live

  def events
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
    sse = SSE.new response.stream
    redis = Redis.new
    redis.subscribe(redis_channel) do |on|
      on.message do |event, data|            
        sse.write(data, event: 'messages.create')
      end
    end
    #render nothing: true 
  rescue IOError
    # disco bro!
  ensure
    redis.quit
    sse.close
  end
end

// also tried without the SSE.new, so just plain response.stream.write(data)
```

My Javascript is simple easy

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/events")
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
  console.log(event);      
}
```

When i call  `/events` in my browser and send some messages - its outputting. but if we connect the socket with JS we get

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/petra/events' failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

can anybody light me up? Are we missing something, or do i have a wrong understanding of what i'm trying to do.

Comment: SSE and WebSocket are different protocols. You can't use one to connect to the other. You should use a websocket library compatible with RoR instead.

Comment: http://pastie.org/10359879 that wont work too? so AC::Live only supports SSE?

Comment: Seems like it. If you want to use SSE you can change your client to use that instead, which is arguably easier to do: `new EventSource("/events");`

Comment: we had that before, working perfectly, but actually we also want to send data (chat system), so we need to go websockets (and also sockets are having better support, regarding caniuse?. main target is thailand)

Comment: Yes, WebSockets is better supported over SSE, and if you want bidirectional communication, websockets is probably the way to go as long as your client browsers support it.

Comment: so, no chance for websockets+AC::Live, right? i need to chose some of those gems

Comment: Seems that way, perhaps websocket-rails is something you should try instead.

Comment: okidoki. write an answer and ill accept it. might help some other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSockets and Server Send Events are different protocols and can't inoperate in the manner you're trying.

The main js API for SSE is `EventSource(url)` ([introductory article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)).

If you want bidirectional communication you would switch the server side to use WebSockets instead. For ruby on rails, [websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails) is a popular library to do this.